# Wizard 5 / Eldritch Knight 3

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spell-slots, eldritch-knight

I’m having trouble finding the answer to my exact question after extensive searching on here and other places. I am currently a Level 3 Wizard / Level 1 Fighter. I aim to focus on my wizard levels but I was thinking about taking Level 3 Fighter to gain access to the Eldritch Knight martial archetype. Basically what I want to know is will being an Eldritch Knight give me access to more spell slots outside of wizard spell slots alone? Also, will it enable me to learn more spells that I could not as a wizard only character. I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for help. What I’m hoping to hear is something like wizard gives me 4 spell slots for level 1 and being Eldritch Knight gives me another 1/2 level 1 spell slots etc etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour].

Comment: We have questions which cover this topic extensivly because it comes up a lot, so I've marked this as a duplicate of those. No worries, we consider duplicates a good thing (they help other find those Q&As). If those don't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: These do not answer my question specifically. Never mind, I’ll figure it out myself.

Comment: One explains how you figure out the character's spell slots, the other explains how you figure out which spells the character knows. If you're asking somebody to do the specific math for you, that's not going to be useful long term. Is there some specific question do you have that they're not answering?